# tangle vs entangle

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between tangle and entangle? They look like similar and can both mean twisting in something. I also know entangle comes from prefixing tangle with *en-*. But it doesn't help to make a distinction between them.

Answer (score 3):

Both are synonyms to each other (meaning getting stuck in a twisted fashion) and can be used interchangeably. However `entangle` is generally used after an explanation of the event

> fish attempt to swim through the mesh and become entangled

Comment: The fishing lines became entangled. His foot was entangled in the wiring. (The Free Dictionary). There is no explanation.